# Not able to print table

Tags: html, node.js

I'm sending the table created in node js to the html web page but the table boundary is not getting printed instead some random characters and symbols are getting printed.

the node js code is :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
 var fs = require('fs')
var googlePlaySearch = require('google-play-search');
var prettyjson = require('prettyjson');
app.use(express.static('public'));
var csv = require('csv');
 var Table = require('cli-table');

app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.htm" );
});


app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {
first_name:req.query.first_name
 googlePlaySearch.fetch(req.query.first_name, function(err, response) {

var data =
'Category,name\n' +
 response.categories + ' ' +
response.name ; 

 var chars = {
  'top': '═', 'top-mid': '╤', 'top-left': '╔', 'top-right': '╗',
  'bottom': '═', 'bottom-mid': '╧', 'bottom-left': '╚',
  'bottom-right': '╝', 'left': '║', 'left-mid': '╟', 'mid': '─',
  'mid-mid': '┼', 'right': '║', 'right-mid': '╢', 'middle': '│'
 };

csv().from.string(data).to.array(function(data) {
   var
     headers = data[0],
     values = data.slice(1),
    aligns = [null,'right'],
    table = new Table({ head: headers, chars: chars, colAligns: aligns })
    ;

  table.push.apply(table, values);
   console.log(table.toString());
 });


 });

 });

 var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

 var host = server.address().address;
 var port = server.address().port;

 console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

and the html code is (index.htm)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Package Details</title>
 </head>

<body>

  <h1><marquee style="color:yellow" >this is a page to find app details..     </marquee></h1>

  <center>

    <form id="f1" action="/process_get" method="GET">

        <h3 style="color:red">Package Name</h3>:<br>

             <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="font-size: 20px">
     </form>
 </center>

 </body>
</html>
```

Please help me with the code

Comment: did you check the character encoding of your file? i.e. is it saved as UTF-8?

Comment: @SimonHänisch character encoding of html file?

Comment: @SimonHänisch yes i did.. I changed the encoding to utf-8 and no output.

Comment: I meant the node js file, but both ;) try to also set the character encoding in the head of your html file: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: if that doesn't work, you can try to use html entities in your `chars` object instead (i.e. replace ╤ with `&#9572;`, see http://graphemica.com/blocks/box-drawing/page/2 for all the html entity codes)